# Mongoose - поле _id: не удаляется

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Код:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("127.0.0.1:27000/testDb");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    memo: String,
    flags: String
});

Operation = mongoose.model("Operation", schema);

new Operation({
    userId: "user",
    amount: 1.13
}).save( function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.error("Error: ", err);
    console.log("Data Before: ", data, "\nType of data._id: ", typeof data._id);
    data.id = data._id;
    delete data._id;
    console.log("Data after: ", data);
})
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/node toTest.js
Data Before:  { _id: 575fc7d0ead69b00187fb1f5,
  amount: 1.13,
  userId: 'user',
  __v: 0 } 
Type of data._id:  object
Data after:  { _id: 575fc7d0ead69b00187fb1f5,
  amount: 1.13,
  userId: 'user',
  __v: 0 }
```

Что за магия? Почему поле `data._id` имеет тип `Object`, а не `String`? Почему это поле не удаляется, а `data.id` не задается? Версия Node.JS: `5.11.1`

UPD > В ходе экспериментов я понял, что Mongoose использует обертку для `data`. Такой код работает:

`data = data.toObject();
    data.id = data._id;
    delete data._id;`

Но нет ли варианта получше?

Comment: Приведу пар ссылок, так как на этот вопрос уже есть масса ответов:

_id - это https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId  
и хороший ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100660/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-avoid-using-automatic-id-field

Comment: @zhenyab, прочитайте UPD вопроса, я уже написал, что понял это. Вопрос в том, как сделать этот код лучше.

Comment: главный вопрос - зачем удалять в данном случае, если id = _id, но _id - проиндексирован при всем при этом

Answer (score 1):

_id нельзя удалить так как это обязательное поле для MongoDB и по совместительству PrimaryKey. Тип поля в модели Mongoose:

```html
const modelMy = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
...
```

Также не забудьте изменить в [валидаторе MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) . 
Лайф хак - использовать виртуальные поля, что б, замапить на _id другое поле. Вставить в модель между описью полей модели и экспортом:

```html
const virtual = modelMy.virtual('someField');
virtual
    .set( function (v) {this._id = v;} )
    .get( function () {return this._id} );
```

Comment: Как быстро отвечают на Stackoverflow! Уже даже не помню, зачем задавал этот вопрос )

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `delete data._doc._id`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]